# <div> is visible for some time even if ng-show is false in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is this div:

```
<div ng-show="messageAvailable" class="message">
    <p ng-bind="message"></p>
</div>
```

that messageAvailable comes from $http request. So, until angular js loads and that request sends response and assigns the value 'false' to $scope.messageAvailable, this div is visible. I don't want it to be visible even for a small period of time.

I tried this:

```
<div ng-show="a=messageAvailable || false" class="message">
    <p ng-bind="message"></p>
</div>
```

and this(at the very beginning of the controller):

```
$scope.messageAvailable = false;
```

Neither helped.

Comment: A plunk/jsfiddle/codepen showing the problem in action would be a help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using ng-if instead of ng-show?

ng-if won't render the HTML nodes within if the expression is false.  At least with Angular 1.3 or later.

```
<div ng-if="messageAvailable" class="message">
    <p ng-bind="message"></p>
</div>
```

In general you should consider ng-if over ng-show/hide, especially when inside an ng-repeat.  It will greatly reduce the number of active watches in the digest cycle and speed up the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide it with styles

**upd**

```
<style>
        .h {display: none;}
        .v { display: block}
</style>

<div ng-show="messageAvailable" ng-class="{'v': messageAvailable,'h':!messageAvailable}"
```

Comment: then it will hidden even when messageAvailable is true

Comment: yep, you are right, it is still invisible becouse there is no visible styling or that, try updated code