# ng-show is visible before hiding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am basically reviving this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191302/div-is-visible-for-some-time-even-if-ng-show-is-false-in-angular-js), but with the slight difference that to me it happens upon page loading.

```
//HTML
<h1>Some very serious message here</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="text !== ''">
    <label class="alert alert-danger">{{text}}</label>
  </div>
</div>

//JS
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngAnimate"]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = '';
});
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvS8k/79/).

Why can I see (even though very shortly) the label? The same happens if I change `ng-if` for `ng-show`.

Comment: Please find [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvS8k/81/) use `ng-cloak`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ng-cloak directive:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-cloak>
```

This should help hiding AngularJS html templates before being loaded.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your controller isn't initialized when your HTML is rendered. You can use ng-cloak as darron614 said, to prevent your HTML template from displaying before it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-cloak

```
<h1>
Some very serious message here
</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="text !== ''" ng-cloak>
    <label class="alert alert-danger">{{text}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```